# Cycle in models in Entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Imagine these models are a part of a social network application. `User` can make a `Group` and can add other users in it(as members) and a user can be a member of the group. I'm using .net core and also entity framework core.

**Models:**

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IList<Group> OwnGroups { get; set; }
    public IList<GroupMember> MemberInGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OwnerUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OwnerUserId")]
    public User OwnerUser { get; set; }

    public IList<GroupMember> Members { get; set; }
}

public class GroupMember : BaseEntity
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API:**

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.OwnGroups)
    .WithOne(x => x.OwnerUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerUserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.MemberInGroups)
    .WithOne(x => x.User).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Members)
    .WithOne(x => x.Group).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When I want to migrate to the database, this error happens:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_GroupMembers_Users_UserId' on table 'GroupMembers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

However, I can **make** this model in `SQL Server` **manually** and there is no problem.
[image]

There are at least two ways to fix it. But I want to know why `EF Core` says, there is a cycle. What's the problem is?

Comment: It's not EF core saying this. It's SQL Server, so no escape, fix it.

Comment: Of course. Your right. Way `SQL server` let me make it manually but by `EF core` doesn't?

Comment: It's not EF Core limitation, but SqlServer. Note the word **cascade** inside the error message. The model you created manually most like does not have `CASCADE DELETE` on one or more relationships. So do the same in EF Core - change one or more `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` and you'll get the same database model.

Comment: I mean it's not `cycling` actually. My problem isn't who says the error.

Comment: @IvanStoev I changed the `Cascade` to `ClientSetNull` and `Restrict` and it works.

Comment: It's not cycling, but has *multiple cascade paths*  from Users to GroupMembers: (1) Users -> Groups -> GroupMembers and (2) Users -> GroupMembers. I know in reality the owner will never be a member of the owned group, but there is no way to tell that to the relational database, hence it counts it as possibility and in turn a cascade delete problem. Btw, this is SqlServer (and may be some other) database limitation - Oracle for instance handles such things w/o any problem.

Comment: @SaeidAmini You can create the model manually because, no doubt, not all FKs in the model are cascading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Get rid of the Fluent API part

```
//modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
//.HasMany(x => x.OwnGroups)
//.WithOne(x => x.OwnerUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerUserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

//modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
//    .HasMany(x => x.MemberInGroups)
//    .WithOne(x => x.User).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

//modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
//    .HasMany(x => x.Members)
//    .WithOne(x => x.Group).HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

And then, based on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), choose one of these cases:

1. Change one or more of the relationships to not cascade delete(make it nullable)

   ```
   public int? OwnerUserId { get; set; }
   ```
2. The second approach instead, we can keep the `OwnerUserId` relationship required(non-nullable) and configured for cascade delete, but make this configuration only apply to tracked entities, not the database.

   ```
   modelBuilder
           .Entity<User>()
           .HasMany(e => e.OwnGroups)
           .WithOne(e => e.OwnerUser)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
   ```

In this way, if we want to delete a `User` and all its `Groups`, we should load both the `User` and its `Groups` in the application(RAM). Look at this:
After running this code, the `User` and all its `Groups` will be removed.

```
var context = new MyDbContext();

var user = context.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == "SampleName");
var groups = context.Groups.Where(x => x.OwnerUser == user).ToList();

context.Users.Remove(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But the code below will throw an exception.

```
var context = new MyDbContext();

var user = context.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == "SampleName");

context.Users.Remove(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Groups_Users_OwnerUserId' on table 'Groups' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I think your bridge table(junction) has a problem.

Try this

```
public class GroupMember: BaseEntity
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }


    public Group Group { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I use this pattern in most of my projects.you can easily add other fields. but I'm not sure the bridge table can inheritance from other tables.

Comment: @GertArnold just checked with the derived class,you are free to use inheritance. It 's working! also, you can select any name for your table you want.

Comment: Does it solve the issue though? I think it still creates cascading foreign keys.

Comment: @GertArnold I checked it again.its working well. this you don't need Fluent API config.I check it with NuGet now. data base updated successfully

Comment: With the exact model as in the question, with EF core?

Comment: @GertArnold  Not EF Core.